# jQuery Events get skipped

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I built a slideshow-menu (using Slide JS - http://www.slidesjs.com/ ) and added a hover-event, so images will already switch when moving the mouse over the menu point. Additionally, when moving out of the whole block, there's a mouseleave event, which sets the image and menu point back to the first one.
Now when I quickly switch between menu points (hover event) and then leave the whole block (mouseleave), it usually skips the mouseleave event (- or it never reaches it because the hover events (including a fade effect) take up too long).

Is there a way to thoroughly work off each event (or at least the last one in a row - e.g. mouseleave or last hover)?

Maybe an image of the website layout helps?
[image]

Red: Hover-Event (changes green content)

Blue: Mouseleave-Event (green goes back to default)

Comment: image doesn't help ... the code you are using is what's needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `fade` effect is the culprit, then try adding a `stop(true, true)` function before your `fade` effect.

```
$(slideshow-menu-selector).on('mouseleave', function(){
    // Reset code here
    $(element-selector).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
})
```

This is just a sample code, based on your question. If you can put up a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net), it would help a lot!

Comment: I tried to make it in Fiddle, but the JS to initiate the Slide.JS itself didn't work. I never used Fiddle before, that's probably why I got trouble with it.
Anyways, this stop function you suggested already did what I was looking for, so thanks!